"Some" as a polarity item?
I'm having difficulties with the concept of polarity items. As far as I've understood: Polarity items are items, such as partitive any, restricted to occurring in certain types of sentence. Some of them have certain structural conditions that needs to be followed as well, for example any and its compounds needing to be c-commanded by an affective constituent. I think I to some degree understand this. My main issue is whether or not the word some could be considered a polarity item or not, as it's a word my lecturer mentioned when going over the topic but never explained further.
Would for example the some in the sentence "I have watched some movies" be considered a polarity item? But where partitive some is commanded by an affirmative constituent instead? Or would it be considered a polarity item only due to the fact that you can't replace quantifier some with any and therefore would have to be rewritten as "I have not watched any movies"? Or would only the latter of the two be considered to contain a polarity item?
My understanding of polarity items as of right now is that they need to be preceded or followed by the appropriate constituent, affirmative if positive and affective if negative. Any in the sentence above is preceded by haven't and some by have, and neither of them can be replaced by the other without having to rearrange the sentence. Is this right?
I might also be way off and in that case I apologise. I've been trying to figure out this for some hours now... Thanks for any help!

The specific context could make a difference, but in general, some in I have watched some movies is a (somewhat weakly) positive polarity item.
You can tell this from the fact that the negated version I haven't watched some movies is a rather unlikely utterance.
It's perhaps more obvious in the very unlikely utterance I haven't made some mistakes. Where negative polarity any works fine as I haven't made any mistakes.

For more on negative polarity lexical elements, have a look at sorely-missed Prof John Lawler's Summary of Negative Polarity Items.

Thank you so much for the response!
Would this mean that whether or not possible polarity items' weakness/strength is dependent on the likeliness of it being uttered in its negated/affirmative version?
So, for example I haven't seen anybody outside being much more likely to be uttered than I have seen anybody outside.
Is this why I haven't found much about positive polarity words, as they more often than not are weaker than the negative ones and often can be used in their negated form?

Well, I have seen anybody outside is so non-idiomatic I expect at least some people (not any people) would say it's actually "ungrammatical". But many native Anglophones (especially, less well educated, and/or in casual contexts) will say I haven't seen nobody - which pedants will dismiss as ungrammatical "double negation" (compare Pink Floyd's facetious We don't need no education). You might find it useful to look at sorely-missed Prof John Lawler's Summary of Negative Polarity Items.

I can't see anything from Prof Lawler about positive polarity items, but some, at least, a few come to mind as elements that wouldn't normally occur with negation. On another tack, note that it's likelihood, not likeliness (there is likeness, but that's a completely different word - to do with similarity, not probability).
